# Does the typename keyword exist in C++, for backwards compatibility with “C templates?”

Tags: c++, c, templates, standards

I’m taking a C++ class, and my teacher mentioned in passing that the `typename` keyword existed in C++ (as opposed to using the `class` keyword in a template declaration), for backwards compatibility with “C templates.”

This blew my mind. I’ve *never* seen or heard tell of anything like C++’s templates (except, perhaps, the preprocessor… and that’s not really the same thing at all) in ANSI C. So, did I miss something *huge* somewhere, or is this a really esoteric extension by `gcc` or something, or is my teacher way off-base?

Comment: Can you get a new teacher?

Comment: To be honest, I really like this teacher. He’s by far the best ‘programming’ teacher I’ve met at this university. I’ll avoid specifying which university (and which teachers), for their sake.

Comment: (To give some comparison, one of the previous teachers, teaching a C course, instructed us to “start every file with the line `void main () {`. There’s so many things wrong with that, I don’t even know where to start… the most glaring being, to me, giving `main()` a `void` return type. That’s so un-UNIX )-:< it made me sick.)

Comment: Consider switching the university then

Comment: There’s no others where I am. Anyway, I’m just taking the one class, mostly out of boredom. And just because he made one mistake, doesn’t mean he’s useless as a teacher d-:

Comment: like some guy below says, maybe with "c templates" he means templates parameterized with C types (`int` for example).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think your teacher is off base.

See [Stan Lippman's post: Why C++ Supports both Class and Typename for Type Parameters](http://blogs.msdn.com/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx) for the real reason why C++ supports both.

Comment: Thanks, man. It’s nearly pushed me over 100 reputation, *finally*! d-;

Comment: The Lippman post a is a good one for answering both this question and explaining why `typename` is sometimes needed in other contexts.

Comment: This link doesn't exist anymore. 404 error. But found it in "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/slippman/why-c-supports-both-class-and-typename-for-type-parameters"

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the phrase your teacher was aiming for was along the lines of "...for backwards compatibility with C ***types***", i.e., recognizing the problem that `template<class T>` is misleading when `T` is a C-style built-in type such as `char` or `int`, as others have said.  *But that's not a class!* :-)

A while back a few GCC folks were [suggesting](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-07/msg01015.html) that making the template machinery available to the C compiler would be a good way to implement C99's `<tgmath.h>`, but that doesn't appear to have come to anything.

Answer (score 5):

No, ANSI C does not support templates.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/keyword_typename.htm

Answer (score 3):

Your teacher is making things up. There's no such thing as templates in C. The `typename` keyword exists for two reasons:

1. It makes more sense to say `template<typename T>` than `template<class T>` since `T` can be non-class types like `int` or `double`.
2. It can be used to resolve parsing ambiguities in declarations like `A::B * foo;`. Does this declare a variable named `foo`, or is it a multiplication expression? (Answer: It's parsed as the latter. To make it a declaration write `typename A::B *foo;` which tells the compiler to interpret `A::B` as a type name, not a variable name.)

See http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such thing as a C template. `typename` isn't even a keyword in C.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem right. typename is not a reserved word at all in C.

Perhaps they misspoke/remembered and were thinking of "C with Classes".

Answer (score 0):

I wish to say that C really don't have a native template stuff, however, you can make it works fine with some kind of a [MetaProgramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), [take a look](http://arnold.uthar.net/index.php?n=Work.TemplatesC) around the web you will find how to...

Another important thing to say is that C is a programming language to general purpose, so a lot of things like Object Orientation, template and some other things can be done with a little more effort.

Projects like Gnome are proof that it can be done and very well.

P.S.: Sorry about my terrible english!!!